# Is there a strategy for coming up with examples of operators for these types of problems?

Tags: linear-algebra

"Give an example of an operator $T$ from $\mathbb{C}^{3}$ such that $2$ and $3$ are the only eigenvalues of $T$ and $T^2-5T+6 \neq 0$."

I was able to find an example after some trial, but I was wondering if there is a general strategy for this problem. Is there something I should be looking out for or trying first here?

Comment: The condition $T^{2}-5T+6I\neq 0$ just means that you can't use a (trivial) diagonal matrix to solve this. So just find a 3x3 non-diagonal matrix whose eigenvalues are 2 and 3.

Answer (score 1):

It's all about testing your understanding of connections between characteristic polynomial, annihilating polynomial and minimal polynomial.

On one hand, since $2$ and $3$ are the only eigenvalues of $T$, the minimal polynomial of $T$ has to be of the form $d(\lambda) = (\lambda - 2)^{m_1}(\lambda - 3)^{m_2}$, where $m_1 \geq 1, m_2 \geq 1$, $m_1 + m_2 \leq 3$ (because the eigenvalues are zeros of $d(\lambda) = 0$). This means the only possibilities of $(m_1, m_2)$ combinations are $(m_1, m_2) = (1, 1), (m_1, m_2) = (2, 1), (m_1, m_2) = (1, 2)$.

On the other hand, $T^2 - 5T + 6 \neq 0$ means $\lambda^2 - 5\lambda + 6 = (\lambda - 2)(\lambda - 3)$ is not an annihilating polynomial of $T$. Thus rules out the possibility $(m_1, m_2) = (1, 1)$ (because $d(\lambda)$ is an annihilating polynomial of $T$).

Therefore, $T$ can be any operator that is similar to
\begin{align*}
J_1 = \begin{pmatrix}
2 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 2 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 3
\end{pmatrix}, \quad \text{corresponding to } (m_1, m_2) = (2, 1), 
\end{align*}
or any operator that is similar to
\begin{align*}
J_2 = \begin{pmatrix}
2 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 3 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 3
\end{pmatrix}, \quad \text{corresponding to } (m_1, m_2) = (1, 2).
\end{align*}